# Ruby: CSV.open with encoding fallback option

Tags: ruby

When opening a CSV file in Ruby with CSV.open, is there a way to set encoding fallback similar to how it's set in String.encode?

Example:

```
CSV.open('file.csv', encoding: 'windows-1252:utf-8')
```

I would like to set something like this:

```
CSV.open('file.csv', encoding: 'windows-1252:utf-8', fallback: {
  "\u0080" => "\x80",
  "\u0081" => "\x81"
})
```

I couldn't find this in the docs, but maybe it's hidden somewhere.

Comment: Not anything I am aware of, but you might `File#read`, then `String#encode` with a fallback and then `CSV#read` this string.

Comment: May be you could find some help with the answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11733076/how-do-i-robustly-parse-malformed-csv/12772298#12772298)